# A textbox need to be visible or Hidden based on radio option selected in Openwrt Luci

Tags: luci

I want to make visible or hidden a textbox based on radio option selected in openWRT Luci.

Is there any way to avoid JavaScript?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yah Raihanhbh it's available in openwrt luci, you need to use dependent. base on luci [documentation](http://luci.subsignal.org/trac/wiki/Documentation/CBI) let describe how depends work.

CBI provides the **:depends()** method on option objects that allow to dynamically show or hide the object field depending on the value in some other field.

the method is called as **obj:depends( some_other_option, value )**. "depends" parameter is linked with "OR"

--**Now let an example**

```
local t=require"luci.model.network".init()
local e=require"luci.model.firewall".init()
local i=require"luci.util"
local e=require"luci.model.uci".cursor()
local u=require"luci.sys".net
```

--**Create model**

```
m = Map("firewall1", translate("firewall"))
s = m:section(NamedSection, "dmz", "")
```

--**create radio button**

```
f1 = s:option(ListValue, "dmz", "Current DMZ Status:") -- Creates an element list (select box)
f1.widget="radio"
f1:value("disable", "Disable") -- Key and value pairs
f1:value("enable", "Enable")
f1.default = "disable"
function f1.write(self, section, value)
    return Flag.write(self, section, value)
end
```

--**TextBox**

```
f2=s:option(Value,"netmask1")
f2:depends("dmz","disable")
function f2.cfgvalue(self,section)
    local val = self.map:get(section, "netmask")--Value.cfgvalue(self, section)
    return val
end
```

--**Return model**

```
return m;
```

above textbox **netmask1** dependent on radio button **dmz**